# onItemClickListener is not working on listview

Tags: android, sdk

I want to open a new activity from a listview.*Opening a new activity in listview*. I have tried setOnclick listener but isn't working properly.
Adapter code is below.*there is no error in thd code*

```
public class MyOffers extends Activity {
static final String TAG = MyOffers.class.getSimpleName();
private View parent_view;
public String separatecheck;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AdapterListBasic mAdapter;
ListView lv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_dth_offers);


    ArrayList image_details = getListData();
      lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dth_list);
    lv1.setAdapter(new AdapterDthList(this, image_details));
    Log.e(TAG, "hfhfhfhhfhfhhfhfofferrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" );
    // listening to single list item on click
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Log.e(TAG, "hfhfhfhhfhfhhfhfofferrrrrrrr" );
           // Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
          //  NewsItem newsData = (NewsItem) o;
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dispoffer.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            // selected item


        }
    });
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class AdapterDthList extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<NewsItemDth> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public AdapterDthList(Context aContext, ArrayList<NewsItemDth> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.headlineView.setText("Amount: "+listData.get(position).getReporterName()+"/-");
        holder.reporterNameView.setText( listData.get(position).getHeadline());
        holder.reportedDateView.setText(listData.get(position).getDate());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView reporterNameView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doesnt show any error but "lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()" is not working

Comment: Post your item Xml and AdapterDthList.java.

Comment: I think you have some error in your XML file, or you may have defined something in Adapter, so kindly update your question with both file.

Comment: @ChetanShanbhag Everyone telling about to post your xml and adapter file. No one can understood your question without your whole code. Kindly update asap.

Comment: @PratikButani I have posted the code

Comment: @pskink onItemClickListener

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using `getApplicationContext()` insted of `Activity` context.. try changing
`Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dispoffer.class);`
to

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(MyOffers.this,Dispoffer.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Chetan Shanbhag you need to add the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` line in root layout of xml file you used to create each row of your `ListView`. In your case it is used in this line.
 `convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);`.
You need to add it in your `list_row_layout.xml` file. You will find it under res>layout directory in Android Studio if thats what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If your row item of list contains focusable or clickable views then `OnItemClickListener` won't work.

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to root layout of your row item . below is an example.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

 // your widgets goes here

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If that doesn't solve your problem . Edit your question with adapter and item xml

Comment: In which XML file?? list latout or adapter layout??

Comment: Adapter's layout XML file .

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
tools:context="com.youtel.paisabox.activity.dth.MyDthOffers">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/dth_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>
```